# Elementary Real Analysis: Cauchy sequences and definition of the real numbers.

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question in my Elementary Real Analysis. The question goes as follows: Let $a={{{(a_n)_n}_\in}_b}_N$, $b={{{(b_n)_n}_\in}_b}_N$ be Cauchy sequences of rational numbers. We say a and b are equivalent if for all $m\in N$ there exists $n_0 \in N$ such that $|a_n-b_n|<1/m$ for all $n \ge n_0$. Prove that this defines an equivalence realtion of the space of all Cauchy sequences of rational numbers. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what an equivalence relation is?

Comment: Yes I do know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $a_n == b_n$ if they are equivalent

To show that $==$ is an equivalence relation we need to show that:
$a_n == a_n$, but this is obvious, take $n_0=1$ for all $m$
$a_n == b_n$ iff $b_n == a_n$, but again this is obvious because $|a_n - b_n| = |b_n - a_n|$

And we need to show that if $a_n == b_n$ and $b_n == c_n$ then $a_n == c_n$. So take some $n_0$ such that $|a_n - b_n| < \frac{1}{2m}$ and some $n_1$ such that $|b_n - c_n| < \frac{1}{2m}$.

Then $|a_n - c_n| \leq |a_n - b_n| + |b_n - c_n| < \frac{1}{m}$ for $m > \max(n_0,n_1)$, as required.

Comment: Hi, could you explain why you choose 1/2m for transitivity?

Comment: $\frac{1}{2m} + \frac{1}{2m} = \frac{1}{m}$, so you split up the error term you have.